# How can I receive an update notification for new versions of installed Flatpak applications?

Tags: flatpak

For example, I installed the Flatpak for Audacity which currently ships version 2.1.3. How can I receive an update notification once version 2.2.0 is out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GNOME Software** will notify you of available Flatpak and DPKG updates if you install the Flatpak backend (`apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`). This is installed by default in most Linux distributions with GNOME Software; except Ubuntu since they want to promote Snap instead (`gnome-software-plugin-snap`).

Comment: As a remark, the `gnome-software-plugin-*` packages are available starting from Artful (Ubuntu 17.10).  They're not available for the as-of-now latest LTS, Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04), or other versions before Artful.